# How to print all columns using AWK

Tags: programming, awk

In [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK), is there a way to print all columns? I do not want to print them like this:

```
printf($1 $2 $3 ...)
```

Is there a way to print all of them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will print all:

```
awk '{print $0}'
```

And to make this long enough: this will print columns 3 to 6:

```
awk -v f=3 -v t=6 '{for(i=f;i<=t;i++) printf("%s%s",$i,(i==t)?"\n":OFS)}'
```

---

OFS is a built-in variable (there are 8: FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR) and is the output field seperator ([more here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)).